# Ubuntu 12.04 freezing upon CD/DVD installation at "installing system"

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, cd

First off, I have a very old computer. I feel it necessary to point out that it has a Pentium 4 processor, I believe 768 MB of RAM, and about 30 GB total on the hard drive. Now, onto my predicament...

I was recently running Windows XP on my computer. It kept having some issues, so I tried Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit. I put in the CD/DVD, and the installation was working fine until it got to "installing system". It froze there for about 3-3 1/2 hours. I figured something must've been wrong, because a computer couldn't be THAT slow. I then took out the CD/DVD and tried again. The same exact thing happened; froze at "installing system".

Could this be an issue with my computer? I did some research and read that others have managed to run it on a Celeron processor (which is older than a Pentium). Others have also said that a computer similar to mine could run Ubuntu 12.04 quite smoothly.

Please help, Trevis/Twistedstar

PS. This is the output of `lshw`

```
ubuntu                    
description: Desktop Computer
product: 8753-8233
vendor: VIA TECHNOLOGIES, INC.
width: 32 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.2 dmi-2.2
configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop
*-core
description: Motherboard
product: VIAP4XB
vendor: VIA TECHNOLOGIES, INC.
physical id: 0
 *-firmware:0
      description: BIOS
      vendor: Award Software International, Inc.
      physical id: 0
      version: 6.00 PG
      date: 05/24/2002
      size: 128KiB
      capacity: 192KiB
      capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb agp ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 1.60GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 4
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: 15.2.4
      slot: Socket 478
      size: 1600MHz
      capacity: 4GHz
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 100MHz
      capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm up pebs bts
      configuration: id=0
    *-cache:0
         description: L1 cache
         physical id: 9
         slot: Internal Cache
         size: 8KiB
         capacity: 16KiB
         capabilities: synchronous internal write-back
    *-cache:1
         description: L2 cache
         physical id: 0
         size: 512KiB
 *-firmware:1
      description: BIOS
      physical id: 516
      size: 1003KiB
      capacity: 1MiB
 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 1d
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 768MiB
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM
         physical id: 0
         slot: A0
         size: 256MiB
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM
         physical id: 1
         slot: A1
         size: 256MiB
    *-bank:2
         description: DIMM
         physical id: 2
         slot: A2
         size: 256MiB
 *-pci
      description: Host bridge
      product: VT8753 [P4X266 AGP]
      vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 01
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: driver=agpgart-via
      resources: irq:0 memory:c0000000-cfffffff
    *-pci
         description: PCI bridge
         product: VT8633 [Apollo Pro266 AGP]
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pci pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         resources: ioport:9000(size=4096) memory:d8000000-d9ffffff memory:d0000000-d7ffffff
       *-display
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: RV100 QY [Radeon 7000/VE]
            vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            version: 00
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 66MHz
            capabilities: agp agp-2.0 pm vga_controller bus_master vga_palette cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=radeon latency=64 mingnt=8
            resources: irq:11 memory:d0000000-d7ffffff ioport:9000(size=256) memory:d9000000-d900ffff memory:d8000000-d801ffff
    *-network
         description: Ethernet interface
         product: 3c905B 100BaseTX [Cyclone]
         vendor: 3Com Corporation
         physical id: 7
         bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
         logical name: eth0
         version: 30
         serial: 00:10:5a:e3:e6:ea
         size: 10Mbit/s
         capacity: 100Mbit/s
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
         configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=3c59x duplex=half latency=32 link=no maxlatency=10 mingnt=10 multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
         resources: irq:12 ioport:a000(size=128) memory:db000000-db00007f memory:30000000-3001ffff
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: VT8233 PCI to ISA Bridge
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 11
         bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
    *-ide
         description: IDE interface
         product: VT82C586A/B/VT82C686/A/B/VT823x/A/C PIPC Bus Master IDE
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 11.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:11.1
         logical name: scsi0
         logical name: scsi1
         version: 06
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: ide pm bus_master cap_list emulated
         configuration: driver=pata_via latency=32
         resources: irq:0 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:a400(size=16)
       *-disk:0
            description: ATA Disk
            product: WDC WD300AB-00BV
            vendor: Western Digital
            physical id: 0
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
            logical name: /dev/sda
            version: 21.0
            serial: WD-WMA7H1262427
            size: 27GiB (30GB)
            capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
            configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=00035ef6
          *-volume:0
               description: EXT4 volume
               vendor: Linux
               physical id: 1
               bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
               logical name: /dev/sda1
               version: 1.0
               serial: 5261f911-4f11-450f-b7bc-d52b8f349eb1
               size: 27GiB
               capacity: 27GiB
               capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink extents ext4 ext2 initialized
               configuration: created=2012-08-18 04:30:06 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/target modified=2012-08-18 04:30:12 mounted=2012-08-18 04:30:12 state=clean
          *-volume:1
               description: Extended partition
               physical id: 2
               bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
               logical name: /dev/sda2
               size: 765MiB
               capacity: 765MiB
               capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
             *-logicalvolume
                  description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                  physical id: 5
                  logical name: /dev/sda5
                  capacity: 765MiB
                  capabilities: nofs
       *-disk:1
            description: SCSI Disk
            product: ZIP 100
            vendor: IOMEGA
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@0:0.1.0
            logical name: /dev/sdb
            version: 14.A
            capabilities: removable
            configuration: ansiversion=5
          *-medium
               physical id: 0
               logical name: /dev/sdb
       *-cdrom:0
            description: DVD writer
            product: DVD RW DRU-530A
            vendor: SONY
            physical id: 2
            bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
            logical name: /dev/cdrom
            logical name: /dev/cdrw
            logical name: /dev/dvd
            logical name: /dev/dvdrw
            logical name: /dev/sr0
            version: 2.1g
            serial: 3
            capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r
            configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
       *-cdrom:1
            description: DVD reader
            product: CD-RW  CRX320E
            vendor: SONY
            physical id: 3
            bus info: scsi@1:0.1.0
            logical name: /dev/cdrom1
            logical name: /dev/cdrw1
            logical name: /dev/dvd1
            logical name: /dev/sr1
            logical name: /cdrom
            version: NYK5
            capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd
            configuration: ansiversion=5 mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,noatime state=mounted status=ready
          *-medium
               physical id: 0
               logical name: /dev/cdrom1
               logical name: /cdrom
               capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
               configuration: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,noatime signature=66b94095 state=mounted
             *-volume UNCLAIMED
                  description: Hidden HPFS/NTFS partition
                  physical id: 1
                  capacity: 701MiB
                  capabilities: primary bootable hidden
    *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: VT82xxxxx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 11.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:11.2
         version: 1b
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:12 ioport:a800(size=32)
    *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: VT82xxxxx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 11.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:11.3
         version: 1b
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:12 ioport:ac00(size=32)
    *-usb:2
         description: USB controller
         product: VT82xxxxx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 11.4
         bus info: pci@0000:00:11.4
         version: 1b
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:12 ioport:b000(size=32)
    *-multimedia
         description: Multimedia audio controller
         product: VT8233/A/8235/8237 AC97 Audio Controller
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 11.5
         bus info: pci@0000:00:11.5
         version: 30
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_via82xx latency=0
         resources: irq:5 ioport:b400(size=256)
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@3:2
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: 00:13:46:63:3e:f8
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2500usb driverversion=3.2.0-23-generic-pae firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.4 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

Comment: @cgubuntu1204 I believe it is just a Pentium.

Comment: @cgubuntu1204 is there any way to check during the installation? if not, I'm unsure.

Comment: I reboot my computer, and upon doing so it told me the main processor; it read "Pentium (R)"

Comment: Yes, it is a 32 bit CD.

Comment: I did that, and it ended with the result of no errors found. Also, when I tried inputing my information under the "who are you?" (the user name, computer name) I got this: "trevis-8753-8233-Invalid-entry-length-2-DMI-table-is-broken-Stop" could this have something to do with it?

Comment: It appears that this might be a problem with your ram. Can you do what the 5th comment said, only instead of `check disk for defects`, run `Test Memory`

Comment: Okay, I managed to run that, and it read as a result again, no errors found. Also...me being my stupid self, I realized (thanks to the memory test), that I have a Pentium 4 processor. I am sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I tried that, and when I tried accessing paste.ubuntu.com, I received a "the server took too long to respond" message. I tried visiting the website on my laptop, same result. Is there any other alternative, or should I wait?

Comment: Can you get to your question by going on the live CD. If so, then just post it directly into your question.

Comment: Yes, I have basically been using the Live CD all along. Also, how would I go about posting code into the question? I tried code sample...and it only properly edited one little section. (I'm very sorry for bothering you about this stuff, I am new to the website.)

Comment: Btw..I noticed you edited Pentium to Pentium R. I do believe that (R) is just impling copyright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this out:

when your computer is starting to boot off the CD, immediately after you see the `ISO Linux...`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Select your language and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now press the down arrow key. Press <kbd>F6</kbd>, and select `nomodeset` and `acpi=off`. The image below will show you:

[image: Other options]

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> when you are done with that. Now you will be able to edit the `Boot Options`. Remove `quiet splash` and after the two dashes `--`, add `nomodeset`. Here is a picture of what it should look like:

[image: edit boot options]

Now you are done. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> over `Install Ubuntu`. This will now load up the installer.

Hope this works for you!

PS, if it still does not work, I noticed that you have an extra CD/DVD drive. Remove it, and start the same process over again.

Answer (score 0):

if you can boot into the live environment, please open Disk Utility from the Ubuntu Dash and check the SMART status of the disk in your computer.

If it says anything like *This disk has a few bad sectors*, the health of your disk has been compromised and you should replace it.