# Lubuntu keeps suspend system while installing

Tags: lubuntu

I am trying to install the 32 bit version of Lubuntu 15.10 on a Dell Inspiron 700m.  I have to use boot option `forcepae` during the install, because the CPU is a Intel Centrino.  While installing, my system keeps sleeping due to some kind of error I believe.  In the command output all it says is that the system is going to suspend.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a graphics compatibility issue, please try to press the <kbd>shift</kbd> key just before the install screen pops up. Then choose the language of your choice. Next you should press <kbd>F6</kbd> and select **nomodeset** from the options. Here are the steps in details: [graphics compatibility](https://askubuntu.com/a/177511/476968). Hopefully this time it will install without issues. See [BootOptions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Ubuntu_CD_Advanced_Welcome_Page_Options) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: It is still going into suspend mode, when I switch the graphical install to text only install using the "Esc" key the system says it is going into sleep mode, so I do not think it is a graphical error.

Comment: I solved the issue by going under the "Other Options" via F6 and selecting ACPI-off.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to disable suspend ability in lubuntu with setting
`HandleSuspendKey` and `HandleLidSwitch` to `ignore` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.

Notice, You have to delete the `#` symbol at the beginning of the line.

This has the advantages, that the pc is not running on full power the whole time (fan on max), special hardware like pcmcia cards are working, the battery symbol is shown and the pc turns off if you shut down it.

Answer (score 0):

The way that worked for me (after all other suggestions failed) was to use the minimal install process and choose the command line install option.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall#Full_install.2C_minimal_install_or_core_install.3F.